# How to validate a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, validation

i have a text box that i enter a range to in a string format, the text in the text box is something like

"1 to 30"

"4 to 75"

so its integer &" to "& integer.
what is the best way to validate this?

Comment: You may want to make your life easier and break that into two text boxes from and to

Comment: Apps not working someone entered 12 2 32, someone else entered 12 too 32, and finally someone entered 12 two 32

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a regular expression that matches two numbers and allows anything in between; but since the user can enter anything, I would concur with @Gratzy, that the best solution is to provide two different fields.

Comment: if i wanted to do this i wouldn't ask the question :) , i have no problem splitting it and getting the min and max values from it but i am not sure how to valdiate it

Comment: With two textboxes, just add a number validator.

Comment: or used a maskedit control, then you can do number "to" number. Otherwise regex, or use split using space as a delimiter, and validate each part.

Comment: Or you could do it key by key with on key press, though that's a fair bit of work. Depends on when you want to validate and how you want to respond to invalid input more than anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect task for [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). In your case, the expression is as easy as

```
^\d+\s+to\s+\d+$
```

Which means:

- The beginning of the string (`^`),
- several digits (`\d` is a digit, the following `+` means: one or more of the previous),
- followed by several whitespaces (`\s` is spaces, tabs etc.),
- followed by the literal string `to`,
- followed by whitespaces and then digits,
- then the end of the string (`$`).

In VB, you’d match it as follows:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\d+\s+to\s+\d+$") Then ' Yes, it matches.
```

This requires [importing the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx).

Regular expressions are an own language to describe strings, so they take a bit getting used to. But they are by far the easiest tool to handle such string validations and simple parsing jobs so learning them is obligatory.

Comment: @user1570048 Ooh, beware though that this doesn’t allow entering either negative numbers or numbers written with an exponent (`1E20`). This requires special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex class, just instantiate a new instance of the Regex class, passing '[1-30]' into the constructor as the pattern, then run the 'IsMatch' method to return a Boolean value indicating whether the subject passed into the IsMatch method is between 1 and 30.

Comment: Regular expressions don’t work like that. You cannot match for a number between 1 and 30 by the way you described.

Comment: Really? I'm not at my computer so can't test, I assumed Regular expressions would work the same way with integers as they do with characters, vote me down!

Comment: They don’t. Regular expressions work on character level, they don’t even know about numbers. Which makes handling things like numbers painful in regular expressions.